# Count the number of times an object appears in an array in matlab

Tags: matlab, class

I have two classes, Good and Market. Every class has its properties. They are as follows

```
classdef market< handle
properties
    name
    goods=good.empty
    budget=0
end
methods
    function obj=market(val1)
        obj.name=val1;
    end
    function buy(obj, item)
        obj.goods(end+1)=item;
    end
    function sell(obj,item,quantity)
        obj.goods=obj.goods(obj.goods~=item);
    end
    function list=l(obj)
        list={obj.goods.name;obj.goods.price1;obj.goods.price2};
    end
    end
```

end

Good

```
classdef good
properties 
    name
    price1
    price2
    quantity
end
methods 
    function obj=good(val1,val2,val3)
    obj.name=val1;
    obj.price1=val2;
    obj.price2=val3;
    end
end
end
```

Everytime I call the method buy, a new item is added to my goods in market. For example if I have 2 goods, good1 ang good2, after 9 times buying them, I have the following result

Columns 1 through 6

```
'Cheese'    'Eggs'    'Cheese'    'Cheese'    'Cheese'    'Cheese'
[    10]    [  20]    [    10]    [    10]    [    10]    [    10]
[    20]    [  30]    [    20]    [    20]    [    20]    [    20]
```

Columns 7 through 9

```
'Cheese'    'Eggs'    'Eggs'
[    10]    [  20]    [  20]
[    20]    [  30]    [  30]
```

Cheese correpsonds to good1. Eggs corresponds to good2.

1. How can I sum all the good1 and all the good2 that I have? the function numel(good1) returns ans=1 which is wrong.
2. I have a property quantity in my goods. After summing up the results how can I have another array of my goods with their corresponding quantities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of accessing a field of an object array is a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Thats why `numel` does not work as you suppose. To receive an array you should enclose the list in braces or parentheses:

```
names={m.goods.name}
prices1=[m.goods.price1]
```

Now `names` is the cell array, containing all the fields `name` of `m`, `prices1` contains fields `price1`. In order to find the elements, containing `Eggs`, we can now use `strcmp`:

```
e= strcmp(names,'Eggs')
```

The number of `Eggs` fields is the number of ones in `e`. Lets count them:

```
eggs_num= sum(e)
```

And now we can sum up the `price1` fields of the elements that we have found:

```
sum(prices1(e))
```